# Have a error using windowapi at asm code, but I can't where to fix it

Tags: assembly, winapi, error-handling, x86, window

I'm using window api to copy a txt file to create same txt file But, I'm having some kind of bug(I think) that doesn't copy the first word of the txt file!

The input is something like this:

C:\Users\User\Desktop\qwe\qwe.txt
C:\Users\User\Desktop\qwe2\qwe2.txt

```
%include "io.inc"

extern _access
extern _MessageBoxA@16
extern _CloseHandle@4
extern _CreateFileA@28
extern _WriteFile@20
extern _ReadFile@20
extern _strcat
extern _strlen
extern _strtok

section .data

    buffer1 times 0xff db 0x0
    buffer1_len equ $ - buffer1
    buffer2 times 0xff db 0x0
    buffer2_len equ $ - buffer2
    
    caption db 'Do you want to Copy?', 0x0
    format db 0x0a, 0x00
    
    error db 'There is no file', 0x0d, 0x00
    error_caption db 'error', 0x0d, 0x00
    
    file db 0x00
    file2 db 0x00
    read_file_pointer times 0xffff dq 0x00
    new_file db 0x00
    read_len times 0xfffff dq 0x00
section .text
global CMAIN

    
filecheck:
    push 0x00
    push buffer1
    call _access
    add esp, 8
    cmp eax, 0
    jne error_message
    
    call copy
    ret
copy:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    
    push 0x0
    push 0x0
    push 0x3
    push 0x0
    push 0x0
    push 0x1
    push buffer1
    call _CreateFileA@28
    mov [file], eax
    
    push 0x0
    push read_len
    push 0xff
    push read_file_pointer
    push dword [file]
    call _ReadFile@20
    
    push dword [file]
    call _CloseHandle@4
    
    push 0
    push 0x80
    push 2
    push 0
    push 0
    push 0x40000000
    push buffer2
    call _CreateFileA@28
    mov [file2], eax
  

    ;Write File
    push 0
    push 0
    push dword [read_len]
    push read_file_pointer
    push dword [file2]
    call _WriteFile@20

    
    push dword [file2]
    call _CloseHandle@4
    
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret
    
error_message:
    push dword 0x0
    push dword error_caption
    push dword error
    push dword 0x0
    call _MessageBoxA@16
    cmp eax, 1
    je program_exit
        
message_box:
    push dword 0x4
    push dword caption
    push dword buffer1
    push dword 0x0
    call _MessageBoxA@16
    ret
    
cat:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    push buffer2
    push buffer1
    call _strcat
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret
    
strlens:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    push format
    push buffer1
    call _strtok
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret
    
CMAIN:
    mov ebp, esp; for correct debugging
    mov ax, buffer1_len
    GET_STRING buffer1, ax
    mov ax, buffer2_len
    GET_STRING buffer2, ax
    
    call cat
    call message_box
    call strlens
    
    call filecheck
    
program_exit:
    xor eax, eax
    ret
```

I can't find where to fix.
I am thinking of somewhere in the declaration in section .data but still I have some problem fixing it

Comment: What do you mean by "first word"?

Comment: For example, if the txt file goes like "Test file for the test" then it would copy "? file for the test"

Comment: Is it always the first full word? That seems strange.

Comment: It's not the first word, it's just the first 3 bytes. Your `file` and `file2` need to be `dd` not `db`.